# Thales' Theorem for Hyperbolic Geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, reference-request

In Euclidean geometry [Thales' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem) says that if you view a diameter of a circle from any point on the perimeter it occupies exactly $90$ degrees in your field of view.

More generally for any segment $s$ and any angle $\theta$ the set of points from which $s$ occupies exactly an angle of $\theta$ in the field of view is the union of two circle arcs.  This follows from the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle_theorem#Theorem).

In hyperbolic geometry Thales' theorem is false.  In fact, there is a distance $d > 0$ such that if you are at distance $d$ from a geodesic then the whole thing occupies exactly $90$ degrees in your field of view.  Therefore on a circle of radius $d$ or more there are points from which a diameter occupies less than $90$ degrees.

At least in the case of a geodesic the set of points from which it occupies $90$ degrees is a nice and well known curve (i.e. an equidistant: a curve at a fixed distance from a geodesic).  In fact the curve is even an Euclidean circle arc in either the Poincaré disk or the upper half-plane model.

My question is the following: Given a finite segment $s$ in the hyperbolic plane, what does the set of points from which the segment occupies exactly $90$ degrees look like?  Is it a well known curve? Has it appeared or been used in relation to other questions?

Also one can ask the same questions for a general angle $\theta$.

**Edit:**  Just realized this is [has been asked before on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33977/poincare-disk-model-is-this-locus-a-known-curve). Sorry.

Comment: This question could be related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33977/poincare-disk-model-is-this-locus-a-known-curve/

Comment: As I mentioned in an answer to the other question, if one positions the geodesic segment in the Klein model to have one endpoint at the origin, then the curve is a circle for which the segment is a diameter. 

Comment: I added this comment to the other question, but since I saw your question first, I'll repeat it here: Google books pulled up the following page from Richter-Gebert's recent book "Perspectives on Projective Geometry", though I can't access most of the discussion: http://books.google.com/books?id=F_NP8Kub2XYC&lpg=PA514&ots=jhnB7ZG5dY&pg=PA514#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Agol Very nice! Thanks!  Do you know of something that works for angles other than $90$ degrees?

Comment: I voted to close this because strictly speaking it is a duplicate; however I much prefer the background and motivation given in the text of this question. +1